# Specific reason for "fragment overlap"?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have not found a question with an answer detailing exactly **why**, **in terms of the Android run-time**, this issue occurs. Can anyone provide this explanation? I am not interested in ways to mitigate this issue (such as setting fragment's root view background color), but want the specific explanation of **why** it occurs.

(I am using v4 support FragmentManager, FragmentTransaction, Fragment APIs).

I have an Activity comprised of a FrameLayout (R.id.fragment_container) and a BottomNavigationView.

Initially in the Activity I add a fragment instance to the FrameLayout:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, donsListFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

donsListFragment (an instance of my `DonationsListFragment.class`) shows a message ("Currently there are no donations.") and a refreshing indicator (using SwipeRefreshLayout) (see first screenshot) until it has retrieved data from a web-service (see second screenshot). I use an [ObservableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.html) instance member in `DonationsListFragment.class` to hold data retrieved from the web-service and control the visibility of the message and a RecyclerView (for displaying the list) via the Data Binding framework.

[image: first screenshot] [image: second screenshot]

If the user taps an item in the BottomNavigationView ("Schedule", for ex.) the following code replaces the fragment in the FrameLayout with the fragment (`frag`) that corresponds with the user's choice:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
        transaction.commit();
```

Sometimes, in this scenario, there is "fragment overlap" (*my own term* :)), see third screenshot below (the "Currently there are no donations." message of `donsListFragment` is still visible (*underlined in the screenshot*) even though the previous code should have *entirely* replaced `donsListFragment` with the Schedule fragment):

[image: third screenshot]

What **exactly** is happening here??

I handle user taps on the BottomNavigationView in an override of `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem)` in my Activity (it implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener):

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actions_item_donations:

                if (donsListFragment == null) {
                    donsListFragment = new DonationsListFragment();
                }

                if (!donsListFragment.isVisible()) {
                    // posting a sticky event will prompt a refresh in DonationsListFragment's onResume()
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new RefreshDonationsEvent());

                    displayFragment(donsListFragment);
                } else {
                    donsListFragment.refreshDonations();
                }

                break;

            case R.id.actions_item_schedule:

                if (schFragment == null) {
                    schFragment = ScheduleFragment.getInstance(orgType);
                }

                if (!schFragment.isVisible()) {
                    // posting a sticky event will prompt a refresh in ScheduleFragment's onResume()
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new RefreshSchDaysEvent());

                    displayFragment(schFragment);
                } else {
                    schFragment.refreshDays();
                }

                break; ...
```

And my `displayFragment(Fragment)` method is defined as follows:

```
    private void displayFragment(Fragment frag) {
            // update title in app bar accordingly
            appBarTitleTV.setText(fragTitles.get(frag.getClass()));

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
transaction.commit();
        }
```

You will see from my `switch` statement previously that I use a [GreenRobot EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) sticky post of a refresh event object to trigger a refresh in `DonationsListFragment`'s `onResume()`. Here is `DonationsListFragment` `onResume()`:

```
public void onResume() {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    OneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None);

    if (EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(RefreshDonationsEvent.class) != null) {
        refreshDonations();
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

And my `refreshDonations()` method initiates an **asynchronous** web service call (using a [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) based web client) before calling `setRefreshing(true)` on the SwipeRefreshLayout that wraps the fragment's layout. The underlying web client callback handling code sends donations retrieved from the server back to `DonationsListFragment` via the GreenRobot event bus.

```
public void refreshDonations() {
        apiClient.donationCurrentDonations();
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
```

Comment: "What exactly is happening here?" -- beats me. As others have indicated, the behavior is identical to if you had used `add()` instead of `replace()`. You might try calling `enableDebugLogging()` on your `FragmentManager` and see what sorts of output that you get. Maybe you're going through some code path that you're not thinking of and is causing different transactions to run than you are expecting.

Comment: Please see my answer below for update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that removing the `SwipeRefreshLayout`s from the fragments' respective layouts and instead adding a SwipeRefreshLayout (surrounding the fragments' swap-in-out FrameLayout) to the containing Activity's layout has stopped the "overlap" from occurring.

So I have seemingly stopped the issue happening without unfortunately being able to definitively say why. Thanks CommonsWare for `enableDebugLogging` suggestion, however I'd started into the layout refactoring before reading it and unfortunately cannot report what the logging would have been (when issue was happening).

It *appears* that having each fragment's View hierarchy include a SwipeRefreshLayout (to indicate data retrieval progress, as shown in my first screenshot) was interfering with the swapping of fragments in and out of the the container.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, donsListFragment);` instead of `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, donsListFragment);`

Comment: I do use replace, as explained. I only use add once, when the Activity is first created, to add the Donations fragment. So I am calling replace when the issue is occurs.

Comment: How do you add your 'empty list text view' (No donations in this case) to the fragment? Programmatically or changing visibility of text view defined in xml?

Comment: I don't add the TextView. It is defined in the fragment's layout xml. I use an ObservableList instance member in DonationsListFragment.class to control the visibility of the message via the Data Binding framework. So in the layout the TextView includes an android:visibility attribute with value @{donations.isEmpty ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" (where donations is bound to the ObservableList).

Comment: Please provide the code you have used to implement the bottom navigation and viewpager

Comment: I am not using a ViewPager. Just a FrameLayout in my activity layout that I swap fragments in and out of. I have added code segments showing how I handle the bottom navigation.

Comment: Can you show how you handle refresh donations event?

Comment: I have added the refresh related code as requested.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

Your issue here is that `.replace()` isn't behaving as you would expect.

In this scenario you begin with the `FrameLayout` named `fragment_container`.

When you call `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, donsListFragment);` you add a new view to activity state.

i.e. you now have 2 views (`R.id.fragment_container` and `donsListFragment`'s view) where before you had 1 (just `R.id.fragment_container`).

However, when you call `.replace()` on the container view, `R.id.fragment_container`, it does not remove the view that was added previously.

i.e. you will still have 2 views (`donsListFragment`'s view and `frag`'s view). This causes the overlap.

**Solutions**

There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Use `transaction.replace()` to insert `donsListFragment` in your (presumably) initial `FragmentTransaction`.
2. When navigating to a different `Fragment` call `.remove()` for `donsFragment` as part of your `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Why do you say I "call .replace() on the container view"? I call transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag); and the Android docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html) say replace(int, Fragment) calls through to replace(int, Fragment, String) which will **"Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container"**. And why should it be necessary to call remove when (again, please refer to the official docs) replace _"..is essentially the same as calling remove...and then add...with the same arguments"..._?

Comment: Using transaction.replace instead of transaction.add in the **initial** display of the donations fragment  _in the onCreate(Bundle) method of the activity that contains the fragment container_ makes no difference in terms of this issue.